# Отключение масштабирования

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Здравствуйте можете подсказать как запретить масшабирование crtl+,ctrl- и другие. Чтобы сайт не двигался, чтобы была блокировка, перепробовал разные способы, но не один не помог. Буду очень признателен кто поможет.

Comment: Попробуйте задавать всем параметрам у которых есть px - vh или vw

Comment: А можно как то js сделать так что бы в самом браузере нельзя было масштабировать

Comment: user-scalable="no" не помогает ?

Comment: Мне нужно не для мобилки, а для пк

Comment: Тогда проверять на наличие события mousewheel но кроссбраузерно...и при наличии отключать т.е preventDefault

Comment: а можете пример написать?

Comment: В сети куча примеров..лень делать..комп выключен

Comment: Учтите, что очень нежелательно запрещать масштабирование страницы: [Please, stop disabling zoom](https://www.matuzo.at/blog/2022/please-stop-disabling-zoom/)